# Wanting to go back to iOS 6 from iOS 7 on Development Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7, restore

Does anyone know of a definitive way of restoring a device back to iOS 6 from iOS7?

I've already got the correct ipsw file for the device, for iOS 6.1.4 (the latest pre-iOS 7 version of iOS 6). When I try and restore through Xcode's Organiser window, I get the following error after selecting the 6.1.4 ipsw for restoration:

> iOS: Restore error 3194 or 'This device isn't eligible for the requested build'

I've been to the following article (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4451), but it doesn't really shed any light on the matter.

I know standard users are struggling to go backwards, but surely there's a way for developers to get back to iOS 6?! Without just avoiding doing any updating?! Surely?!

Am I just being naive or a bit thick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to downgrade from a newer version of iOS. Initially, there is a grace period where Apple signs the installation of an older iOS version, however for the iOS6->iOS7 transition, this grace period has expired.

For the future reference, always make sure to keep at least one development device unupgraded, so you can continue testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it's a big shame. Especially when you can now download old versions of apps. Surely you should still be able to create test devices on older OS's. Unfortunately the pre-iOS7 device we had was updated by an un-experienced member of the none development staff. Wrists slapped.

Comment: I hear your pain. You are welcome to open a bug report for the development tools.